# Jquery UI dialog/modal form disappears when called by from button

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

OK here is my issue, I copy the jquery UI modal/dialog code directly from the Jquery UI site, and the example works perfect. The modal pops up with a form and the whole thing is flawless. When I try to call the same dialog from within a form (trying to add a new record) the dialog flashes on the screen and then is hidden. If I remove the button calling the dialog from the form and place it before or after it works just fine again. Driving. Me. Crazy.

Code below:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/resources/demos/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <style>
        body { font-size: 62.5%; }
        label, input { display:block; }
        input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }
        fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }
        h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }
        div#users-contain { width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }
        div#users-contain table { margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
        div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }
        .ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em; }
        .validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.3em; }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        var name = $( "#name" ),
            email = $( "#email" ),
            password = $( "#password" ),
            allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( password ),
            tips = $( ".validateTips" );

        function updateTips( t ) {
            tips
                .text( t )
                .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
            setTimeout(function() {
                tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
            }, 500 );
        }

        function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
            if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
                o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
                updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
                    min + " and " + max + "." );
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
            if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
                o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
                updateTips( n );
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Create an account": function() {
                    var bValid = true;
                    allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

                    bValid = bValid && checkLength( name, "username", 3, 16 );
                    bValid = bValid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
                    bValid = bValid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );

                    bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter." );
                    // From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
                    bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
                    bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );

                    if ( bValid ) {
                        $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
                            "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" + 
                            "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" + 
                            "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>" ); 
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            close: function() {
                allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
            }
        });

        $( "#create-user" )
            .button()
            .click(function() {
                $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
            });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
    <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

    <form>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>


<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
    <h1>Existing Users:</h1>
    <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
        <thead>
            <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Password</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>John Doe</td>
                <td>john.doe@example.com</td>
                <td>johndoe1</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<form id="myform">
    <button id="create-user">Create new user</button>
</form>    

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. It works fine if you use an Input instead of a button.

```
<form id="myform">
    <input value="Create new user" id="create-user" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to what webNoob answered, the problem is the  tags around your button. `<Form>` constructs require an `<input>` button (type="button" or type="submit").

Answer (score 0):

Write your jquery code inside `function pageLoad() {}` instead of `$(function() {});`.
Hope this will work for you.